# Synchronize Exchange copies in Apache Camel

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-camel

According to the documentation for onCompletion() events in Apache Camel, a copy of the exchange is used there and the processing runs in a separate thread. Apparently this is also true when using the EventNotifierSupport because  I am setting some exchange properties in a processor, and then I have a method similar to

```
public void notify(EventObject event) throws Exception {

    if (event instanceof ExchangeCompletedEvent) {
    //..get exchange properties and print them using event.getExchange()
    }
}
```

It appears that the properties I set in the processor are not available in this "Completed Event" just the same as they arent available when I am using onComplete() in the DSL.

How do I merge together to apparent copies of the exchange so that I can reliable get the properties that are set/modified in the other processors of the route?

Thanks

Derek

Answer (score 0):

Actually the properties added in processors taking part in the exchange ARE available in both of these callbacks i.e. in `onCompletion()` and `EventNotifierSupport#notify()` .

The minimal example demonstrating this behavior can be reproduced by registering the following  `EventNotifierSupport` callback on `CamelContext`.

```
// Create listener
EventNotifierSupport eventNotifierSupport = new EventNotifierSupport(){

  @Override
  public void notify(EventObject event) throws Exception {
    if (event instanceof ExchangeCompletedEvent) {
      assert ((ExchangeCompletedEvent) event).getExchange().getProperties().containsKey("ADDED");
    }
  }

...

}

// Register listener in CamelContext
CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
camelContext.getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(eventNotifierSupport);
```

If you create a route with the [processor](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) which sets property to messages sent to it...

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:start").process(new Processor() {
      @Override
      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getProperties().put("ADDED","ADDED");
      }
    });
  }

});
camelContext.start();
camelContext.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:start", "addPropertyToMe");
```

... you will see that assertion in listener always passes. This is in line with Camel documentation which says that copy of the exchange will be sent to the listener **after** the transaction is completed (i.e. the exchange has been modified).

You problem lies elsewhere. I will help you, if you provide me a minimal example of the case where properties are set in processor but missing in the callback.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get back to you sooner - just noticed i had an answer. Can you tell me what version of Camel you are using? I can't seem to get the same behaviour you are seeing. Thanks

Comment: Hi Derek. I'm using Camel 2.9.2.